# Split network into two using one router

Tags: networking

I using my home internet for online gaming while my siblings and parents use it for streaming videos because of which I face high pings in online games. I have one router. Is there a way I can split my connection into two so that I use one for gaming separately and the rest of the people at my house use the other network and I dont get ping issues. Thank You!

Comment: Make and model or router you currently have?

Comment: Keep in mind that splitting your local network is completely different from splitting the uplink internet connection... and it really sounds like your problems are with the latter, not the former.

Comment: Is your router QoS (Quality of Service) capable?

Comment: Yes, I have the QOS menu where there is bandwidth control and traffic statistics option. My router model is Tenda 11N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok... not a lot of good news. 
I looked up your actual Tundra 11N router hardware; it's a pretty weak device. But that doesn't seem to be your weakest link.

From the traceroute info, that the admins rejected that I dug up, your local ISP NayaTel is trash. 
You have timeouts from:

58-65-175-252.nayatel.pk [58.65.175.252]
in both attempts. 
That is the ISP's device that you're connecting to from your house; all your traffic goes through it

You're ISP is not performing well. 
I would definitely run a few more pings and traceroutes; maybe to some more local sites. then tell them that you're getting time outs from them on your exit interface.

But this is actually super interesting seeing your traffic flow from Pakistan. but going overseas is definitely not helping.

As far as your gaming issue, 
First, I should have asked are you hard wired in? You definitely should be

Second, on your game, can you select a more local server? or even a server that is geographically different than your current one?

Last, Can have I upvotes please? 
I am digging pretty deep into your solution. Thx

But your ISP is your main problem. What connection type from ISP are you using?
CAble, DSL, cellular?
Hopefully, you and ISP can fix it with a few modem resets

Thanks!!

Comment: Im not wired in with an ethernet cable, I just use wifi because the router is like 1 meter away from my device so I didnt think it would make any difference.
I play CSGO mostly. The closest official server I have is in dubai. My average ping to dubai is around 70 and the next closest server I have is in Singapore whose average ping is 120 ms via direct link but these spike a lot when someone else uses internet.
The connection I have with ISP is via a cable that is in WAN port of router.

I did upvote your comments but the site says I have less than 15 reps so it doesnt count. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, Thank you for trying.
You absolutely should hardwire anything in that you can ever.
I got a roku media streamer 2 feet from an AP and I still hardwire it; it goes from ok to high def.
not only that there is a whole list of reasons why you should connect with a cat 5e minimum cable

Comment: You really  should call your ISP and explain your gateway timeout issue. If you   got that fixed in a 20 min call; it would substantially improve your gaming experience

Comment: Okay, Thank You Sir!

Answer (score 1):

You could, if your router supports VLANs. Most domestic ones don't.
However, even if you can, that is unlikely to help you. The link from your router to your ISP is always going to be the bottleneck, not your local LAN, and essentially, everyone in your house using the Internet is competing for bandwidth on that link.

Comment: Thank You ! ,

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the router's web interface
Give yourself and parents, and living room; wherever the bill payers are, Premium priority or queueing.

You don't want to get caught by customer service.

Just remember will be relative to the slowest setting.
So, if the priorities goes  from 1-10
and you use 9 and 10; 9 will be the junk priority, the same as using 1 and 10

Please up vote if helpful

Comment: My router doesn't have that priority option. Instead I can limit bandwidth of certain devices based on their IP assigned by router which doesn't solve my problem since network is the same. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

That might still do it for you. 
It will require a bit of testing on you part.
Think of it like a pie, there's only so much.
what youre doing is saying you and the bill payers get so much guaranteed. 
Then everyone else gets to fight over the remaining pie. 
So if you gave your machine 30%, and your folks 30%; the rest of the house would have 40%. 
one thing to consider is that routers don't only set that aside when youre active, you always have that dedicated to you, regardless if youre using it.

What router model to do have?

Comment: I have Tenda 11N. I do have this option where I can dedicate a certain amount of bandwidth to my device but this doesnt solve my problem and I still get high ping because the root network is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your router; Please confirm that it only has a 100mbps WAN port.

Also please perform and post a couple trace routes to where ever; google, facebook, wherever.

It's either your router is super old or ISP is trash.

There's not a whole lot you can do about either without changing gear or ISP; but at least you can know where you issue lies

**

```
C:\Users\saqib>tracert google.com
Tracing route to google.com [172.217.19.174]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     2 ms     3 ms     4 ms  58-65-175-252.nayatel.pk [58.65.175.252]
  4     4 ms     4 ms     3 ms  172.16.11.113
  5     4 ms     3 ms     4 ms  172.16.11.5
  6    45 ms     5 ms     3 ms  58-65-165-42.nayatel.pk [58.65.165.42]
  7     6 ms     4 ms     3 ms  203.135.5.69
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9    60 ms    39 ms    41 ms  74.125.118.170
 10    40 ms    41 ms    41 ms  172.253.51.55
 11    44 ms    50 ms    48 ms  209.85.249.247
 12    48 ms   122 ms    81 ms  zrh04s07-in-f174.1e100.net [172.217.19.174]
Trace complete.
C:\Users\saqib>tracert facebook.com
Tracing route to facebook.com [157.240.7.35]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1     1 ms    <1 ms     2 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    28 ms     8 ms     2 ms  58-65-175-252.nayatel.pk [58.65.175.252]
  4   190 ms    76 ms     6 ms  172.16.11.113
  5   223 ms   100 ms    26 ms  172.16.11.5
  6     6 ms     4 ms    13 ms  58-65-165-42.nayatel.pk [58.65.165.42]
  7    11 ms     4 ms     3 ms  tw136-static181.tw1.com [119.63.136.181]
  8   134 ms   170 ms   106 ms  110.93.252.99
  9   120 ms    23 ms    26 ms  110.93.252.190
 10   145 ms   106 ms    99 ms  ae11.pr03.sin1.tfbnw.net [157.240.67.228]
 11   103 ms    98 ms   270 ms  po101.psw04.sin6.tfbnw.net [157.240.47.111]
 12   292 ms   247 ms   159 ms  173.252.67.199
 13   214 ms   135 ms    99 ms  edge-star-mini-shv-01-sin6.facebook.com [157.240.7.35]
Trace complete.
C:\Users\saqib>
```

**

Comment: I dont see the option to add Images here so I added the result of trace route to facebook.com and google.com in your last answer. Also, I can confirm that my router has 100 Mbps WAN Port. And several other ports through which you can connect LAN to PC